# How to sort a column in one table based on the rank in another table

Tags: hive, mapreduce

I have a table Table 1 that has User_ID and Item_List where items are arranged randomly

```
Customer_id   Item_List
22              1,4,3,2
24              6,3,2,1
23              4,5,7,8
```

Table 2 has the ranks of the item according to the highest value

```
Item_Id   Item_Rank
  1          8
  2          5
  3          3
  4          4
  5          2
  6          7
  7          1
  8          6
```

I want to produce a Table that has Customer_id with the corresponding Item List ranked according to the Item Rank in Table 2

```
Customer_id     Ranked_Item_List
   22             3,4,2,1
   24             3,2,6,1
   23             7,5,4,8
```

I don't know any efficient method to do it in hive. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think in 2 different ways, create your UDF to avoid the explode or

```
select customer_id, collect_list(item_id) from (

select customer_id, item_id, item_rank from
table1 lateral view inline(item_list) item_id join
table2 on table1.item_id = table2.item_id --this should be done as mapjoin if your rank table is not big 
)  distributed by customer_id, sort by item_rank;
```

Like I said before, depending on the size of your data, you could create an UDF to apply the sort at mapper level based on your lookup table